# CASE Statement to COALESCE in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a COALESCE statement in SQL as follows.

How can I use COALESCE function in SQL?

I have so far coded as

```
COALESCE(IFRM.NAME + '_' + IFRM.TAG,  + '_' +ISNULL('_'+ LFRM.NAME, ''))+ '-->' + '_'+ ITO.NAME +'_'+ ITO.TAG +ISNULL('_'+ LTO.NAME, '') AS TEST,
```

Mine yields:

```
TEST
DAL_L-->_JBU_U_HAL
JBU_U-->_UAE_E
AAL_L-->_KLM_M_ASA
(null)
(null)
```

below are the tables I use for the CASE Statement

```
Main:
ID  FRM_IAD_ID  TO_IAD_ID   FRM_ATL_ID  TO_ATL_ID   FRM_ORD_ID  TO_ORD_ID   FRM_LAX_ID  TO_LAX_ID
9014    3215        1618                                                                1149
9014    1618        1407                                                    1149
9051    1600        1601                                                                1137
9051    1601                              1688                              1137
9059    6108                                                    9764

IAD:
ID  Name    tag
1407    UAE E
1600    AAL L
1601    KLM M
1618    JBU U
3215    DAL L
6108    EVA A

ATL:    
ID  Name        Tag
1688    Japan Airlines

ORD:
ID  name    Tag
9764    QTR

LAX:
ID  Name    Tag
1137    ASA
1149    HAL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a method that uses `COALESCE()` and `STUFF()`:

```
(STUFF(COALESCE('_' + IFRM.NAME, '') + COALESCE('_' + IFRM.TAG, '') + COALESCE('_' + LFRM.NAME, ''),
       1, 1, ''
      ) + '-->' +  -- if you want spaces, use `' --> '`
 STUFF(COALESCE('_'+ ITO.NAME, '') + COALESCE('_' + ITO.TAG, '') + COALESCE('_' + LTO.NAME, ''),
       1, 1, '')
) AS TEST,
```

The idea is to prepend `'_'` to all components, and then to remove the first one using `STUFF()`.

I note that the `CASE` has spaces around the arrow.  Your sample code does not.

Some other databases support a function such as `CONCAT_WS()`, which makes this much simpler.

Comment: Thanks for your quick solution. when running the above, it worked but for some reason, it did not catch this part: KLM_M_ASA --> JAPAN AIRLINES
EVA_A --> QTR

Comment: I am checking it in the meanwhile

Comment: still got stuck on this part. Would you able to check, Mr. Linoff?

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff - I have figured it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert Case to Coalesce.  Coalesce is just shorthand for a case statement in which each value is tested for null.  Your case statement structure is preferred over trying to jam it into a Coalesce statement and you will not be able to cleanly test multiple fields in the Coalesce structure.

It looks like you may be asking how to prevent returning null from your Case statement.  You'll need to add an Else statement that always evaluates to a not-null value.

Incidentally, the final element of a Coalesce statement is also handled as an Else clause.  There is no requirement that Coalesce returns a not-null value.  A null can be returned as long as a data type is assigned.

Comment: @ Wes H, thank you for your feedback. is there a better way to use the CASE Statement for my current CASE Statement?

Comment: I think your Case statement is just incomplete.  You need to finish the expressions that would test for and return the additional airlines.  You should also add an else statement to prevent a null value.  Maybe something like ELSE 'Unknown' END.  If you post some sample data, I'd be happy to help with it.

Comment: Thanks all for your help! Joe